# Нужна ли запятая (однородные или неоднородные определения)?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

**Большое( ) истинное искусство, то, которое называется Откровением Иоанна, и то, которое его дописывает.**

Нужна ли здесь запятая? И как наверняка определить однородные члены в подобных случаях?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Большое, истинное искусство.**

Это однородные определения. Можно использовать два вида проверки:

1) Однородные определения раскрывают **какую-то общую тему**, в данном случае тему  величия искусства: большое, истинное, высокое. Эти определения являются синонимами **в данном тексте.**

2) В случае неоднородных определений первое прилагательное относится **к сочетанию второго прилагательного и определяемого слова**, то есть: *большое (истинное искусство)*. Но это неверно, так как *истинное искусство* не определяется словом *большое*.

Comment: Почему истинное искусство не может определятся словом большое?

Comment: Имеется в виду, что нельзя среди "истинного искусства" выделить большое "истинное искусство" или "малое "истинное искусство", "Истинное и большое"  определяют слово "искусство" независимо друг от друга, они сходны по значению, то есть образую однородный ряд определений, отнесенный . к слову "искусство".

Comment: Теперь стало гораздо понятней. Но вот еще один случай:  где мать уже платит десять рублей за совершенно обыкновенный, зеленый фаберовский карандаш. Я не поставил запятую после слова "обыкновенный" и ошибся! Но, согласитесь, среди "зеленых фаберовских карандашей" можно выделить обыкновенные и ,ну хотя бы необыкновенные. Укажите, пожалуйста, на мою ошибку. (Просто я постоянно делаю ошибки в подобных случаях, а скоро писать диктант по русскому)

Comment: Совершенно обыкновенный и  зеленый не являются однородными, это оценка и цвет карандаша. Берем зеленый фаберовский карандаш (явно неоднородные определения) и добавляем к этому сочетанию свою оценку.Для сравнения:  однородные определения   раскрывают одну тему, произносятся с перечислительной интонацией и по значению близки к синонимам, а этого здесь нет.